# Magento 2 Advanced pricing higher than base price

Tags: magento2

I have a site build where I need to set the product price to be higher than the base price when the customer group logs in. I am trying to do it using the advanced pricing tier but Magento 2 ignores prices that are higher than the base price.

Anyone know a way around this?

Comment: Is there any solution to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

its pretty lame but in Magento 2 you can only have tier pricing lower than the base product price.  If you set it higher it will show the lowest price available which is the default.